# Azure node sdk blob folder upload similar to cli upload-batch

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-js

In azure cli the command

```
az storage blob upload-batch --source <source folder> --destination-path <destination path> --destination <destination>
```

is it available the same api in the javascript sdk @azure/storage-blob or in another package?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this feature is not available in any SDK.

If you are using `@azure/storage-blob`, you would need to list files in a folder yourself (using [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module) and then upload each file using [`uploadFile(string, BlockBlobParallelUploadOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-blockblobclient-uploadfile) method which is what `az storage blob upload-batch` is doing.